# Method with @Cacheable is not working as expected in Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am trying to cache List in a Class as follows:

```
Class Person{
     @Autowired
     PersonService personService;
      .
      .
      .
      .
     @Cacheable("allStrings")
     public List<Strings> getAllStrings(){
        return personService.getStrings();

     } 


}
```

personService has getStrings() which will return all required strings. Eventhough I made getAllStrings() in Person class as Cacheable , cache is not created.

Is it because of proxy? How can I made above method cache without caching getStrings() in service?

Can't @Cacheable can't create cache if method is getting data from other service?

Comment: did you enable the cache using @EnableCaching? Check this url for example on caching - https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Comment: @Cacheable doesn't create the cache.  Is caching enabled?  [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) might help.

Comment: yes, enabled caching using <cache:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Point to note: one more cache is created in another class, where a map is returned from  method, which is created inside method is getting cached.

Comment: I'm guessing it is not cached because it has no 'key' or input given to the method.. create a dummy parameter getAllString(int keyParam);  and in the annotation @Cacheable("allStrings",key="keyParam")

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: Caching should be enabled in the configuration file .